# ng-click not working on li when used in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am using li in ng-repeat like this

```
   <ul class="pagination">
                        <li ng-repeat="page in vm.totalPages" ng-click="vm.statechange(page); $event.stopPropagation()"><span>{{page}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
```

for some reason the click is not working. Any suggestion ?

**updated js code**

```
        vm.stateChange = function (page) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        var storeCommandGet = storeCommandResource.get({ $skip: page + "0", $top: $scope.countPerPage, $orderby: "Serial" });
        storeCommandGet.$promise.then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.value;
            $scope.storeCommandsTableParams.reload();
        });

    };
```

update fiddler added

i tried recreating the problem here

http://jsfiddle.net/qqy90w1f/

Comment: Please add _relevant_ and _complete_ code, both HTML, JS

Comment: provide the complete code, at least the controller

Comment: I am confused.  What is vm?  An instance of your controller?  I am used to seeing such things attached to the $scope.  I could not reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/2mrxn7oc/3/, could you modify this fiddle to produce your problem?

Comment: vm is a controller as sytanx as in 

<div ng-controller="storeCommandsCtrl as vm">

Comment: i tried updating here
http://jsfiddle.net/dmsp0yks/

Comment: Your updated fiddle just gives "Argument 'MainCtrl as vm' is not a function, got undefined" in the console.  Do you in know what version of angular this syntax was introduced?

Comment: it was used in angular 1.2

Comment: i am so soory every one. i spent hours on it and it was a type. it is working without any propagation stop thing. 
apologies once-again

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o5f0aryd/2/ updated fiddle to use a newer version of angular that can use your controller syntax.  I still cannot reproduce your ng-click problem, though; care to take a crack at breaking this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was a typo

in html i am using   statechange
however the function name is stateChange

rest is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do `$event.stopPropagation()` within the `ng-click`.  You should move that into `vm.statechange()`

Comment: i tried that but the thing is ng-click is not triggering. so it wont reach vm.statechange()

Answer (score 0):

you not bind **ng-click** method with $scope. see this code:

In HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="page in vm.pages" ng-click="logout(page); $event.stopPropagation()"><span>Click me to change page to page  {{page}}</span></li>
```

In AngularJS

```
$scope.logout = function(number) {

    console.log('page change to', number);
    vm.pageData = 'pumpkin ' + number;
}
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rOKZHKbumbEa78eisciZ?p=preview)

Comment: its a controller as syntax. there is no issue with it. it was a typo. i answered my question.

Comment: you mean you do not want to any work on ng-click. like condition based

Comment: no nothing really. just a change from vm.statechange to vm.stateChange  worked for me. i also took out propagation stop event.